# SQL Server: calculate field data from fields in same table but different set of data

Tags: sql-server-2008, field

I was looking around and found no solution to this. I´d be glad if someone could help me out here:

I have a table, e.g. that has among others, following columns:

```
Vehicle_No, Stop1_depTime, Segment_TravelTime, Stop_arrTime, Stop_Sequence
```

The data might look something like this:

```
    Vehicle_No  Stop1_DepTime   Segment_TravelTime  Stop_Sequence  Stop_arrTime
    201         13000           60                  1
    201         13000           45                  2
    201         13000           120                 3
    201         13000                               4
    202         13300           240                 1
    202         13300           60                  2
    ...
```

and I need to calculate the arrival time at each stop from the departure time at the first stop and the travel times in between for each vehicle. What I need in this case would look like this:

```
Vehicle_No  Stop1_DepTime   Segment_TravelTime  Stop_Sequence   Stop_arrTime
        201         13000       60                  1           
        201         13000       45                  2           13060
        201         13000       120                 3           13105
        201         13000                           4           13225
        202         13300       240                 1
        202         13300       60                  2           13540           
        ...
```

I have tried to find a solution for some time but was not successful - Thanks for any help you can give me!

---

Here is the query that still does not work - I am sure I did something wrong with getting the table from the database into this but dont know where. Sorry if this is a really simple error, I have just begun working with MSSQL.

Also, I have implemented the solution provided below and it works. At this point I mainly want to understand what went wrong here to learn about it. If it takes too much time, please do not bother with my question for too long. Otherwise - thanks a lot :)

```
;WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.PlanAbfahrtStart,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Fahrzeit, ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.PlanAbfahrtStart AS Stop_arrTime
    FROM     ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32
    WHERE    ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id, t. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.PlanAbfahrtStart, t. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Fahrzeit,t. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz, r.Stop_arrTime + r. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Fahrzeit  AS Stop_arrTime
    FROM    recCTE AS r
    JOIN     ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32 AS t
    ON      t. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id = r. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id
    AND     t. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz = r. ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz + 1
)
SELECT  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.PlanAbfahrtStart,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Fahrzeit, ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.PlanAbfahrtStart,
CASE WHEN Stop_arrTime =  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.PlanAbfahrtStart THEN NULL ELSE Stop_arrTime END AS Stop_arrTime
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id,  ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32.Sequenz
```

Comment: What is the primary key of your table? Does each `Vehicle_No` appear only once, or does `Vehicle_No` and `Stop1_DepTime` uniquely identify a trip (or is it some other column you haven't shown us)?

Comment: Each Vehicle_No appears only once as it also serves as trip number. Also: Thanks for the quick reply and solution -  I am trying to implement it right now.

Comment: I've edited my answer to correct your version of the query. You don't need to fully qualify the column names when table aliases are being used (`recCTE as r`, `ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32 AS t`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure this works:

```
SELECT a.Vehicle_No, a.Stop1_DepTime, 
       a.Segment_TravelTime, a.Stop_Sequence, a.Stop1_DepTime +
  (SELECT SUM(b.Segment_TravelTime) FROM your_table b 
   WHERE b.Vehicle_No = a.Vehicle_No AND b.Stop_Sequence < a.Stop_Sequence)
FROM your_table a
ORDER BY a.Vehicle_No
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I´m trying it and will get back to you when I know if I did it.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive CTE solution - assumes that each `Vehicle_No` appears in the table only once:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(Vehicle_No  INT
,Stop1_DepTime   INT
,Segment_TravelTime INT 
,Stop_Sequence  INT
,Stop_arrTime INT
)
INSERT @t (Vehicle_No,Stop1_DepTime,Segment_TravelTime,Stop_Sequence)
VALUES(201,13000,60,1),
(201,13000,45,2),
(201,13000,120,3),
(201,13000,NULL,4),
(202,13300,240,1),
(202,13300,60,2)


;WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT Vehicle_No, Stop1_DepTime, Segment_TravelTime,Stop_Sequence, Stop1_DepTime AS Stop_arrTime
    FROM    @t
    WHERE   Stop_Sequence = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.Vehicle_No, t.Stop1_DepTime, t.Segment_TravelTime,t.Stop_Sequence, r.Stop_arrTime + r.Segment_TravelTime  AS Stop_arrTime
    FROM    recCTE AS r
    JOIN    @t AS t
    ON      t.Vehicle_No = r.Vehicle_No
    AND     t.Stop_Sequence = r.Stop_Sequence + 1
)
SELECT Vehicle_No, Stop1_DepTime, Segment_TravelTime,Stop_Sequence, Stop1_DepTime,
CASE WHEN Stop_arrTime = Stop1_DepTime THEN NULL ELSE Stop_arrTime END AS Stop_arrTime
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY Vehicle_No, Stop_Sequence
```

**EDIT**
Corrected version of OP's query - note that it's not necessary to fully qualify the column names:

```
;WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  Zaehl_Fahrt_Id,  PlanAbfahrtStart,  Fahrzeit, L32.Sequenz,  PlanAbfahrtStart AS Stop_arrTime
    FROM     ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32
    WHERE    Sequenz = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id, t.PlanAbfahrtStart, t.Fahrzeit,t.Sequenz, r.Stop_arrTime + r.Fahrzeit  AS Stop_arrTime
    FROM    recCTE AS r
    JOIN     ZAEHL_2011.dbo.L32 AS t
    ON      t.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id = r.Zaehl_Fahrt_Id
    AND     t.Sequenz = r.Sequenz + 1
)
SELECT  Zaehl_Fahrt_Id,  PlanAbfahrtStart,  Fahrzeit, Sequenz,  PlanAbfahrtStart,
CASE WHEN Stop_arrTime =  PlanAbfahrtStart THEN NULL ELSE Stop_arrTime END AS Stop_arrTime
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY  Zaehl_Fahrt_Id,  Sequenz
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I´m still trying to implement and will let you know once done.

Comment: Ok so I tried to implement this but run into following problem: the moment I run this, it seems to disconnect from the database server the table is in and I get "Could not find server 'databasename' in sys.servers. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @tfp - Does the same thing happen if you run my example without modification?

Comment: No, tested that first and wokred fine. When I modified I skipped the part where the table is created and instead load a table from the database.

Comment: Is any error message returned when the connection is broken? If the resource govenor is enabled on your server, it might be evaluating the query as too expensive to execute - however, this should return a message.

Comment: It seems off. This is the full msg I get: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Zaehl_Fahrt'.
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server 'ZAEHL_2011' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.` Zaehl_Fahrt is a field name and ZAEHL_2011 the database name - I just translated the names into English for easier understanding.

Comment: @tfp - Could you edit the question with your query - the error message suggests there's a syntax problem which it will be difficult to debug without seeing the whole thing